# Getting Oracle client to work on Windows 7 RC

Tags: oracle, windows-7

Has anyone had any luck in getting an Oracle client to install and work with Windows 7 RC? I went and upgraded from Vista to Windows 7 but having terrible problems getting my Oracle databases to work...

Comment: I have just also tried the Oracle basic client. However, still no luck as on loading Toad and trying to connect to the database I get the error message "Cannot load OCI DLL: C:\Oracle\oci.dll"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phew I eventually worked it out. I downloaded the Oracle Instant Client x86 and copied that and setup up my environment variables (PATH, LD_LIBRARY, TNS_ADMIN). The problem I had before was that I downloaded the x64 version which won't work with Toad which is an x86 app! As soon as I installed the x86 version the problem was solved....

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues.

After downloading the Oracle 10g client for Vista (10203_vista_w2k8_x86_production_client.zip) from the Oracle web site, I unzipped the files, right-clicked on setup.exe, and selected Run As Administrator.

Within the Oracle Universal Installer, I selected Administrator, clicked the Next button, and then selected the Oracle home name and path and clicked the Next button.

As mentioned in other answers, the installer failed on the next screen, "Product-Specific Prequisite Checks".  The specific failure was "Checking operating system requirements..."  in the third column, there is a check box (which was not checked).  I clicked in the check box and the installer changed the status to "Not executed".  When I clicked the Next button, it warned me that the install may fail.  I clicked Okay.  I was able to install without further issue.

It is not intuitive and the Oracle 11g client may be different, but this worked for me.

-Weston

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. What I did to solve this problem was:
- right click on the setup
- choose Troubleshoot Compatibility
- it will popup a window "Test Compatibility settings for the program". It tells me which version is it compatible with and Windows 7 will activate that setting for you. In my case was Windows XP service pack 2 is the setting used to install this Oracle 10g client
- click on the button "Start the program" it will run the installer
- done

Answer (score 1):

It Worked with me, I had to do the following: (all after installing oracle in either compatibility mode or skipping the OS check results)

1- Set up the %Oracle_Home% in the environment variables.

2- Configured "tnsnames.ora, listener.ora and sqlnet.ora" to make sure they match

3- Replaced a malfunctioning DLL for sql*plus (I found the original one in the setup's temp file, just by using search from windows)

4- Logged into sqlplus from command line (sys /as dba) and created a user with high privileges (cuz you can't build a repository with "system" or "sys"

5- Used this new user to create the repository from the RAU (Repository Administration Utility), and here you go!

Comment: Yep I don't have any problem running on Windows 7 x64 RTM with the latest basic client

Answer (score 0):

Read here: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3454893&#3454893

Comment: I had already seen that but don't really understand what they mean by "invoking the installer with the -ignoreSysPrereqs flag". I did try that from the command line but with no success

Comment: no - there was no error message, the installer just suddenly closes not long after initiating the installation...